# Datatables using the row number in a link

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have an ajax server-side table and I want to simply add a column with a icon and a link.

I have

```
{"targets": 4,
      "data": null,
      "defaultContent": "<a href='#'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a>"}
```

This will place the link and the icon fine.

My problem is when I wish to inject the table.row(this).id() so I can replace the # with something like:

```
"edit.php?id=" + table.row(this).id
```

I have tried

```
"defaultContent": "<a href='" + table.row(this).id() + "'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></a>"}
```

but it falls over.

Something stupid I know but help would be greatly appreciated.

```
                    ],
```

Comment: Are you there, or should I delete the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I tried everything but eventually found that full[] is what is return from the ajax and one of the items is not a numerical index but the DT_RowId with "row_" added, so it became a rather simple task of string the first 4 characters and so the code is

```
{"targets": 4,
                        "data": 'DT_RowId',
                        render: function(data, type, full, meta) {
                            return '<a href="edit.php?id='+ data.substring(4) +'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>'
                        } 
                    },
```

. And it works fine. Thanks for your help.